# ios Custom UIButton scale setImage down not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have problem in scale down setImage size if I add UIButton by programmatically whereas if I add the UIButton by storyboard, the UIButton size remain correctly.
The Image is 128x128, I want to shrink down to 30x30

[image]
Top one is created from using storyboard, Bottom is created from using programmatically

These are the methods I tried, none able to shrink the image...

```
let checkBox = UIButton(type .system) 
checkBox.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
checkBox.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
checkBox.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
checkBox.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0)
checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0)
```

Image is set/update on runtime
    checkBox.setImage(UImage, for: .normal)

With suggest using checkBox.frame.size.width, checkBox.frame.size.height
the image becomes correct size but the UIButton now have extra space.
Like the image below. I update image on touchUP UIButton
[image]

Comment: I managed to solve it.
checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0)
checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15.0)

was correct direction, except I have to set it to isActive = true...  what a stupid idea setting it also extra code to active...

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
checkBox.frame.size.width = 30
checkBox.frame.size.height = 30
```

Comment: no, it didnt work. Do I have to scale down the image file use in the project??

Comment: your func works when I update by setImage, but on the process of add still remain huge image size like my question's screenshot, UIButton only the image shrink, but the UIButton size still huge

Comment: sry, I don't really get what your goal is. Can you provide more informations in your question, like what you did in your storyboard or what do you mean exactly by "but on the process of add still remain huge image size"?

Comment: Ok let me repeat what I want,  If add a UIButton by adding from storyboard, the Button size is constraint to 30 x30 like the screenshot at the top.
Whereas if I add UIButton by programmatically, the UIButton becomes same as the image size (128 x 128) which is not I wanted.

So I want to check if I didnt contraints properly

Answer (score 0):

> The Image is 128x128, I want to shrink down to 30x30

One obvious solution, in that case, is to shrink the *image*. Redraw the image into a 30x30 graphics context at 30x30 size and extract the resulting image. Now you have a 30x30 image. That's the best way; it is a waste of memory to hand the runtime a way oversized image and ask it to display it smaller.

Now, if you want to use constraints to size and position the button, that's fine, but you are not doing that correctly. First, you have forgotten to set the button's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`. Second, you have to supply enough constraints not only to set the button's height and width but also its horizontal and vertical position.